# ngAfterCiewChecked clientHeight not working with line breaks - Angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular 2 application where i've managed to set up a functional [Gridify](https://github.com/hongkhanh/gridify) page.

I tricker it with a homemade ngAfterViewChecked:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() { 
    var selector = document.querySelector('.read-grid');
    // The only reason i'm using numOfTimes is that ngAfterViewChecked is runned 4 times on each pageload. It's fine with only running gridify on the last and fourth time. 
    if (selector != null && this.numOfTimes == 4) { 
      this.gridify.createGrid(selector);
    }
    this.numOfTimes += 1;
  }
```

It's almost showing as it should: A 5 column grid-view. The only problem is that on some objects with a longer headline, that has a line break or two, the vertical space (margin) is missing. See image:

[image]

*If i reload the page the objects are placed as they should. If i reload without cache, the problem appear again.*

When Gridify places the objects it uses `.clientHeight` to find the top attribute for each element.

I found that if i set a custom height for the heading on each element - for example 20px - everything is working as it should.

[image]

So my conclusion is that the first load's `.clientHeight` is setting the height of the element without taking the line breaks of the longer headings into account. How can this be?

Is it something with `ngAfterViewChecked`? Is it called to early or what am i missing?

It's the same in Safari, Chrome and Firefox so it doesn't look like it is a browser problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that the font i use for the heading, was called late.

I had an early font call for "Roboto" but later on it was changed to "Libre Baskeville".

That font "Libre Baskeville" is much wider than Roboto, so the heading had line breaks the `.clientHeight` wouldn't detect because it measured the height based on the first font, that was called.

When i changed the CSS to only have one font call - everything worked as it should!